# How to save url images in database from assets in codigniter?

Tags: php, mysql

I saved the images in `../assets/images/` and I want to save links for each image in the database that can display them in view with foreach. How do I save all the images in the database so for each to have an id?

Comment: Can you include the code which is saving your files?

Comment: have you tried it by yourself? If so, show us your code..

Comment: I copied directly from the computer in assets/images.

Comment: I don't use uploader for introduce images in '../images'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem is that you don't know from which URL / dir-level the images will be called, use absolute path in your views and it won't matter:

```
<img src='/assets/images/123.jpg' />
```

Edit. I guess my assumption was wrong. You don't need a DB to just display them. If you do, amend the code below to insert them into the DB where it echos the image tag instead.

The followiung will loop over your directory, grab jpg, png and gif files (as long as they have lowercase extension) and creates appropriate HTML image tags.

```
        $path = 'assets/images';

        $img = array();
        if ($handle = opendir('.'.$path)) {
            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                $n++;
                if  (       (substr($entry,-4)=='.jpg') || (substr($entry,0,4)!='.gif') || (substr($entry,0,4)!='.png') ){
                    $img[$n]=$entry;    
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }

        foreach($img as $v){
            echo "<img src='$path$v' />";
        }
```

Generally, try to describe your problems better and show some work you have already done before asking a question here.

Comment: I could do that if I had some pictures, but if I have 1000?I want to go through with one foreach all and display them in view as gallery.{foreach $items as $item}  

            <div>{$item->content|nl2br}</div>